# Hide .php add a slash

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-rewrite

This script works perfect it forces the trailing slash and hides the .php extension

**BUT!** it does not redirect people going directly to the .php extension.

How can I also force people going directly to the file.php to /file/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please don't add "NEED HELP!!!111", we understand that by you posting here :) (sorry, don't know the answer)

Comment: Sure Znarkus sry

Comment: Can you use the `code sample` feature next time also, makes it much easier to read your example.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be a few errors here:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This declares to the next rule should only occur if the filename is not a file, your `.php` is a file so that would fire false.

This should work, or at least set you on your way:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

`!-d` ensures that the requested path is not a directory; this solves potential issues like `images/` leading to `images.php` instead of your images directory.